# Font Embedding is working strangely

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-family

I have a webpage which displays one label containing font as `font-family:OCR A Extended`. This page contain nested web page which can be navigated through forward and backward button. Suppose the total nested page is 20, in this case till 15 the font is coming fine as expected after that for rest of the pages it is getting changed to default font of the page i.e. `Times New Roman`.
Also this is not happening frequently, its happening once in 100 times but as the issue is unavoidable so looking for the possible fix for this.

I searched and went through this URL also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533034(v=vs.85).aspx but with no success.

Please help me and bear if the question is too vague.

Comment: Weird stuff, maybe try to add the font to the requested element every time you load a new section on the page

Comment: Each every click need to call the scripts for fonts.